# Maven filtering web.xml for Tomcat embedded in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, log4j, web.xml

I currently have the situation where I need to 
1) have external log4j.properties
2) the location of the log4j.properties is configured in web.xml as a property placeholder, the value of the property is read from the POM.
3) the placeholder is populated at build time i.e. when the .war is created

So far, so good - the app locates the log4j at the location specified in the POM and produces log files. However, this only works when the app has been deployed as a .war to a standalone Tomcat instance. The next requirement is to be able to deploy it to Tomcat embedded in Eclipse, a step that doesn't involve Maven as far as I can tell. Is there any way of forcing the web.xml to have its property placeholders populated when deploying to an embedded Tomcat instance?

Thanks in advance

Angus

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

yes, I did come up with a solution in the end. Include the config below:

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>${log4j.properties.location}</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>60000</param-value>
</context-param>
```

context.xml:

```
<Parameter name="log4j.properties.location" value="file:/usr/local/etc/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/log4j.properties"/>
```

And you should be good to go.